# Rails devise for unregistered users or soft-users to access contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a contact form and this can be accessed by even an unregistered user(visitor) and a mail will be sent on contact form submit.

Following https://codediode.io/lessons/364-gradual-engagement-with-Now frails-and-devise, I've overridden current_user and authenticate_user! in registrations controller and thankfully it redirects to localhost:3000/visitors but the index page doesn't load up and devise is throwing an error: "Completed 401 Unauthorized".If I paste same methods in application controller as it supercedes registrations controller, it doesn't even load up localhost:3000 as soft_token is not a column in users. But I don't want to convert soft users to registered users and hence don't need soft_token.

How should I load contact form?

Here's my code. TIA.
visitors/#index

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <%= f.hidden_field :soft_token, value: current_user.soft_token %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Enter your name", label: "Your Name" %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, prompt_text: "Mention email for contacting you back." %>
      <%= f.select(:subject, :subject_id, options_for_select([['Site Feedback', 1], ['Ask a Question', 2], ['Report a problem', 3]])) %>
      <%= f.text_area :message, placeholder: "Enter your question.", label: "Message" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-sm pull-right" %>
  </div>
```

Routes.rb:

```
post 'visitors/contact', to: 'visitors#contact' 
match 'visitors' => 'visitors#index', :as => :visitors, :via => :get
devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: "devise_override/registrations"}
```

visitors_controller

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController
def index
end

def contact
    h = JSON.generate({ 'name' => params[:name],
                        'email' => params[:email],
                        'subject' => params[:subject],
                        'message' => params[:message] })

     VisitorMailer.contact_email(@name, @email, @subject, @message).deliver_later(wait_until: 10.hours.from_now)
    redirect_to :root_url, notice: "Message sent"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I resolved it myself as there was before_action: authenticate_user in application controller so it applied to all controllers. However, using this SO link, I resolved it: [How do I make a before_action to run on all controllers and actions except one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302866/how-do-i-make-a-before-action-to-run-on-all-controllers-and-actions-except-one)